# how to change string into int in databricks

Tags: scala, date, databricks

I have a variable that holds a string, it actually is a date but I want to change it to int to concatenate it with numbers. below is my code

```
val pfdtm = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusDays(2)   
val fileDate =DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd").format(pfdtm)

pfdtm: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2020-02-21T19:48:57.763Z
fileDate: String = 2020_02_21
```

As you see the fileDate is a string, how can I change it to int?

Comment: It may just be my ignorance, but how can `2020_02_21` be an `int`?

Answer (score 0):

`String` can be converted to `int` with `"11".toInt;` or using `Integer.parseInt("11");`. However, in the case you describe both methods will throw an exception, as `2020_02_21` is not a valid integer. You can try getting rid of `_`, but still, something's not right about the idea of using date as integer. 
Could you please describe in a bit more detail, what are you trying to achieve? What int do you want to get, and what will you do with it afterwards?